# jPanel doesn't redraw, waiting for server messages

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I'm creating a connect four game with sockets: 1 server running and two clients that should connect to play the game. I'm having some troubles with the jPanels that are not updating because of the sockets (I think).

When the game (client) starts, you get a jPanel with input box for the IP address and a submit button. If the submit button is pressed, I want to display a message that the game is being prepared and it's waiting for a second player to join.

```
submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!input.getText().equals("")) try {
            prefs.put("SavedIp", input.getText());
            errorLabel.setText("Preparing game and waiting for other players...");
            parentLayout.startGame(input.getText());
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException timeout) {
            errorLabel.setText("Server timed out.");
        } catch (IOException ioeException) {
            errorLabel.setText("Server not found!");
        } finally {
            setTheCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        }
        else errorLabel.setText("Enter an IP adress");
    }
});
```

However in the startGame method, a new GamePanel is created, and in that constructor a new PlayField is created and in that PlayField a new connection is created with sockets.

Once it's connected, it runs a method `checkForNextAction` to see if it receives a message from the server. It keeps running that method until the server sends a message.

**Problem: I don't see the message appear when I press submit. Instead it hangs until a second player joins, and then the server sends a message that the game can start and the gameboard is shown. Can't I just make the message change instantly to the text that I've set? The jPanel probably doesn't update because it's running a method and waiting for a message to come.**

I have a similar problem in-game. When a player puts a coin in a column, this move is sent to the server but the coin isn't drawn on the jPanel. Instead it hangs/freezes. The other client makes his move and **only then** the jPanel of the first client gets updated with the coin from the first move ànd the coin from the other player in the second move. So it seems the move only gets drawn after the other player makes a move.

Does anyone have an idea? I tried to use `this.revalidate()` and such things but I can't seem to force the jPanel to update before he executes the startGame method.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a Swing threading problem, since your code that waits, pauses the Swing event thread, freezing all GUI painting and user interaction. The solution: use a background thread such as a SwingWorker to do the waiting for you. Please check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

---

Something like,

```
  submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!input.getText().equals("")) {
           prefs.put("SavedIp", input.getText());
           errorLabel.setText("Preparing game and waiting for other players...");

           final ParentWorker parentWorker = new ParentWorker(input.getText());
           parentWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                       if (SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE == evt.getNewValue()) {
                          setTheCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
                          try {
                             parentWorker.get();
                          } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                             // here's where you check for your socket or io exceptions
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 });
           parentWorker.execute();
           // parentLayout.startGame(input.getText());
        } else {
           errorLabel.setText("Enter an IP adress");
        }
     }
  });
```

and...

```
class ParentWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
  private String text;

  public ParentWorker(String text) {
     this.text = text;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
     parentLayout.startGame(text);
     return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to implement SwingWorkers!